# Extra row appearing in QTreeWidget PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I've a piece of code in which I've added two sub-items to a `QTreeWidget` parent item. The sub-items are set to be "editable".

I'm facing two problems here:

1. There appears an extra row with *empty* editable items. (I want "Min" and "Max" in the same row)

[image]

2. If I change an editable item to an *empty string* then it appears as if there is nothing, I would like to have some sort of a highlighter that there is an empty field in here(some sort of a box)

[image]

How can I get around these issues?

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.FilterList = QTreeWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FilterList)
        self.setWindowTitle("Form")
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,500)
        self.generateData()

    def generateData(self):
        self.FilterList.setColumnCount(3)
        self.FilterList.setHeaderLabels(["Filter Questions"])
        DifficultyNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Difficulty"])
        self.FilterList.addTopLevelItem(DifficultyNode)
        self.FilterList.itemChanged.connect(self.handleItemChanged)
        EasyNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Easy"])
        EasyNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        NormalNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Normal"])
        NormalNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        HardNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Hard"])
        HardNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        HardNode.setFlags(HardNode.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        MinNode = QTreeWidgetItem()
        MinNode.setText(1, "Min")
        MinNode.setFlags(MinNode.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        MaxNode = QTreeWidgetItem()
        MaxNode.setText(2, "Max")
        MaxNode.setFlags(MaxNode.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        
        DifficultyNode.addChild(EasyNode)
        EasyNode.addChild(MinNode)
        EasyNode.addChild(MaxNode)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(NormalNode)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(HardNode)
        

    def handleItemChanged(self, item, column):
        if item.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('Item Checked', item.text(column))
        elif item.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
            print('Item Unchecked', item.text(column))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

Comment: Typo: `MinNode.setText(2, "Max")` --> `MaxNode.setText(2, "Max")` ?

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for pointing out the typo, but the things still looks pretty much the same.

Comment: It's not only when you edit them, there will also be a box when you delete the "Min" or "Max" text and the item is deselected.

Comment: @alec Yes I've understood that much. Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. I don't want a box in column one. I only want it ```only over the items which are editable``` ("Min" and "Max" in this case) and that too from the beginning.

Comment: @alec I want the user to actually know where he has to enter/edit the values. The moment I delete the "Min", "Max" in this case, the end user will never be able to know where he has to enter the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "Min" and "Max" on the same row, use only one QTreeWidgetItem and set the text for both columns.

If you want a permanent box, an option is to set the `itemWidget` of a QTreeWidgetItem to a QLineEdit and connect its `editingFinished` to set the item text.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.FilterList = QTreeWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FilterList)
        self.setWindowTitle("Form")
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,500)
        self.generateData()

    def generateData(self):
        self.FilterList.setColumnCount(3)
        self.FilterList.setHeaderLabels(["Filter Questions"])
        DifficultyNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Difficulty"])
        self.FilterList.addTopLevelItem(DifficultyNode)
        self.FilterList.itemChanged.connect(self.handleItemChanged)
        EasyNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Easy"])
        EasyNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        NormalNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Normal"])
        NormalNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        HardNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Hard"])
        HardNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        HardNode.setFlags(HardNode.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        MinNode = QTreeWidgetItem()
        
        DifficultyNode.addChild(EasyNode)
        EasyNode.addChild(MinNode)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(NormalNode)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(HardNode)

        self.setTextBox(MinNode, 1, "Min")
        self.setTextBox(MinNode, 2, "Max")

    def setTextBox(self, item, column, text):
        box = QLineEdit(text)
        box.editingFinished.connect(lambda: item.setText(column, box.text()))
        self.FilterList.setItemWidget(item, column, box)

    def handleItemChanged(self, item, column):
        if item.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('Item Checked', item.text(column))
        elif item.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
            print('Item Unchecked', item.text(column))
```

Comment: Could you please also tell me how to highlight the editable text field? In the current scenario the moment the text is changed to an empty string, it gives a feel to the end user as if nothing exists there.

Comment: @deepanshu See revised

Comment: please have a look in the "UPDATE" above, the solution doesn't seem right.

Comment: @deepanshu See revised #2

Comment: Yes, now it's working as desired. Thanks a lot.